# JPA call different Entity(metamodel) class for filter condition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a question regarding filter condition in JPA, whether it is possible to call another Entity class only for filter condition

I have a method in `EmployeeDAOImp` called `findEmployee` which will be called in ManagedBeans when a JSF page is loaded. When user puts a filter condition in JSF's datatable, it searches the corresponding Entity class which is `Employee` (`Employee_` metamodel)

I would like to know whether it is possible to class another Entity class named `EmployeeAll_` only for filter, i.e. when user applies a filter instead of `Employee_` class?

Difference between `Employee_` and `EmployeeAll_` class is first one doesn't have all the employee records(only limited to his department and latter has all the employees(all departments). Both return same set of columns fom database.

Any help is highly appreciable.

**EmployeeDAOImpl class**

```
public void findEmployee(Employee employee) {
        try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> e = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> emp = c.from(Employee.class);
        e.orderBy(cb.desc(emp.get("employeeNo")));
        c.select(emp);  

            CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Employee> empCount = countQ.from(Employee.class);
        countQ.select(cb.count(empCount));

           String employeeNo = employee.getEmployeeNo("");
           List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
              if (employeeNo != null) {
                ParameterExpression<String> pexp =
                cb.parameter(String.class,"employeeNo");
                Predicate predicate = 
                cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.employeeNo),pexp);
                criteria.add(predicate);
            } 
                TypedQuery<Employee> q = entityManager.createQuery(c); 
                if (employeeNo != null) {
         q.setParameter("employeeNo", employeeNo+"%");      
                }
```

Comment: This sounds like a very strange db design, are you sure it is necessary to keep the very same records in two different tables? Have you defined a OneToOne relationship?

Comment: @perissf Records are in same table in database. `Employee` Entity is referring to a view called `employees_view` which will have only records pertaining to logged in employee's department. If he wishes to search for a employee who is not in his department, then I would like to search through all records and hence I thought of using another Entity which will be mapped to `all_employees` view.

Comment: Well, then I suggest to define the Entity Employee that maps the entire table, and to avoid handling the employee_view directly in the java code, because it adds confusion without real added value

Comment: @perissf So to get the records pertains to logged in employee, I could use a where condition in `Employee` Entity?

Comment: Store the logged-in employee information in a session scoped bean, inject the bean by means of ManagedProperty annotation, pass it to the dao service responsible of building the query, and finally, yes, use it in the query conditions

Comment: @perissf if you post as an answer, then I will be glad to accept it. And I would like to know what is the advantage of of storing in session scoped bean and injecting in DAO class? Any example will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mapping `all_employees_view` as an Entity, because it shows essentially the same object type as Employee.

Store the logged-in employee information in a session scoped bean, inject the bean by means of ManagedProperty annotation, pass it to the dao service responsible of building the query, and finally, yes, use it in the query conditions.

**Department**

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
}
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private Department department;
}
```

**UserBean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {
    private Employee user;  // + getter, setter. The property is set during login
}
```

**EmployeeBean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EmployeeBean {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userBean}")
    private UserBean userBean;  // + setter
    // this bean retrieves the records pertaining the logged-in user's department:
    Department userDepartment;
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        userDepartment = userBean.getUser().getDepartment();
    }
}
```

Finally, let your DAO service implement a find method that takes `userDepartment` as input argument.

Comment: Thanks perissf for your solution, I will try this approach.